# How to fix OpenSSL.SSL.Error while using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to fetch data from website. When the crawler has been working for a while, I always got ssl error:

```
Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', '', 'unexpected eof while reading')]>
```

At first I thought it was too many requests at same time, so I added custom settings to my spider

```
custom_settings = {
    "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS" : 1,
    "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP" : 1,
}
```

But the problem remains.

Then I try to run my spider one link by on link like below

```
os.system("scrapy crawl website -a links=link1")
os.system("scrapy crawl website -a links=link2")
os.system("scrapy crawl website -a links=link3")
os.system("scrapy crawl website -a links=link4")
...........
```

It's ok!

My puzzle is why does my crawler work but not after a while? What's the `twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error` and how to solve it.

below is output of `scrapy version --verbose`

```
Scrapy       : 2.6.3
lxml         : 4.6.2.0
libxml2      : 2.9.5
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.6.0
w3lib        : 1.22.0
Twisted      : 21.2.0
Python       : 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
pyOpenSSL    : 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022)
cryptography : 37.0.4
Platform     : Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably just a dropped connection.  You need to catch it and resubmit.

Comment: I try it by add errback handler, but the problem still remains